Where is the flaw in this argument about line segment length?
Examine the line segment on the Cartesian plane between $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$.
This line segment can be formulated using set notation as $L = \{x=y, 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$.
This line connects $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$.
By the Pythagorean theorem, the length of this line segment is equal to $\sqrt{2}$.
Further, let there be a set of two line segments, one from $(0, 0)$ to $(0, 1)$ and another from $(0, 1)$ to $(1, 1)$.
The sum of these line segments is $2$, and together they connect $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$.
Suppose we form a new set where we half the line segment's lengths and have twice as many such that there are line segments from
$$(0, 0) \to (0, 0.5) \to (0.5, 0.5) \to (0.5, 1) \to (1, 1).$$
The sum of these line segments is still $2$.
Let the number of line segments in the set approach infinity, and call this set $S$.
All points in $L$ are within $S$.
All points in $S$ are within $L$.
Therefore, $S=L$.
The sum of the line segments that form $S$ is $2$.
The length of $L$ is $\sqrt{2}$.
So, $2=\sqrt{2}$.
This occured to me the other day, and it has bothered me since. This is by no means a rigorous argument, but I cannot find an issue in the logic at any step, and the conclusion is clearly wrong.

cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4
